# Flutter project ios can't install after upgrade to latest version

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

1. I can't install pod
2. the project was working with `flutter version: 2.10.3` after i upgrade to latest
   version Channel stable, `3.3.4`, now i can't install project on both IOS and android  i
   am getting problem. the image attached for both IOS and android problem *

[image: issue attached with images]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_ios/changelog#250) of the package `stripe_ios`, the minimum deployment target of ios you can set is 12.0.

So, open your `runner.plist` file with Xcode and change the `minimum_deployment_target` to 12.0 or not recommended, but, you can downgrade the `stripe_ios` package to version [`2.4.0`](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_ios/changelog#240) or less.